# Get a players name from their UUID

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a quick and easy way to resolve a Minecraft players UUID to their IGN? I'd prefer something as easy as:

- A server-command like: `playername xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`
- A website that resolves it for me

I've looked around but can't seem to find anything of the sorts.

Comment: http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#UUID_-.3E_Profile_.2B_Skin.2FCape

Comment: Awesome. I can work with that. If you post it in the answers I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update: Use [namemc.com](https://namemc.com/)

No need to cURL, create your own REST clients, or to use one.

---

There isn't a way to print a user's UUID in-game. However - Your method works.

> If you are using a white-list, you can view the whitelist.json file to get a mapping of UUIDs with their player names – Avaq
> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190188/75275

Whitelisting/opping/banning someone and then finding out their UUID from the ops.txt, banned.txt and whitelist.txt files work, but you may unexpectly give them/revoke their access to the server.

(ie. I banned you... Accidentally while trying to find out your UUID and then forgot to unban)

---

Alternatively, you can find out their UUID by querying the Minecraft web API.

> [wiki.vg/Mojang_API#UUID_-.3E_Profile_.2B_Skin.2FCape](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#UUID_-.3E_Profile_.2B_Skin.2FCape)
> [Get a players name from their UUID](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190185/get-a-players-name-from-their-uuid#comment257773_190185) – mid_kid

Because it uses HTTP and special inputs alongside its commands (querys) to the server, you cannot use a web browser. You'll have to use a program that allows custom HTTP commands, rather than your standard `GET http://www.google.com`, or as otherwise known as "Google, load me your frontpage." or `POST http://upload.[somesite].com/[Unique access key] [Insert file contents]`, which is uploading a file to a server... ie. Uploading pictures to StackExchange.

**If you have Google Chrome, you can download this extension that allows you to post custom HTTP requests. Even non-generic ones.**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm

---

[image: Input, output]

While you're doing it, ensure that you have clicked the "JSON" button at the bottom. This will tell the server that "This [text] is in json format, and not raw text."

In this example, an input of:

```
Content-Type: application/json
["aytimothy"]
```

using `POST https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft` gives a return of:

```
[{"id":"29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119","name":"aytimothy"}]
```

meaning, user "aytimothy" (me), have a UUID of "29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119".
*UUIDs does not reveal a client's login. You can only log in/logout/etc. with the client token, access token or the account's username/password.*

---

> Hi. Thanks for your expansive answer! I'm using cURL to achieve a POST request using the following command: `curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft -d '["Avaq"]'`. You might want to extend your answer further by adding that option. I'll still accept it though. :) – Avaq
> [Get a players name from their UUID](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190185/get-a-players-name-from-their-uuid/190219?noredirect=1#comment257869_190219)

*Note: I've never used cURL, so sorry if any of the commands do not work.*

Just to point out: I accidentally did the method to find out the UUID from a username.
*You can get a username from an UUID by going to: [https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/[UUID]/names](https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/%5BUUID%5D/names)*
For example: Mine is https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119/names

So pretty much, the command you're looking for is:

```
CURL https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/[UUID]/names
```

For me:

```
CURL https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119/names
```

But anyways - To send a POST request (that's if you want to turn a username into its UUID):

```
CURL -H "content-type: application/json" -D "["username"]" https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft
```

I'm not sure if the middle `"["username"]"` bit works because of the way cURL phrases the quotes that are inside another set of quotes.

**If cURL does not allow for content to have extra quotes within it, there is no way you can do that with the command line.**
Also, you should also be expecting for a code 200 (Request was successful, got it... And sending result now.) followed by a reply to your query.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your expansive answer! I'm using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to achieve a POST request using the following command: `curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft -d '["Avaq"]'`. You might want to extend your answer further by adding that option. I'll still accept it though. :)

Comment: No idea what that (the program/programming library) is, but I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a white-list, you can view the `whitelist.json` file to get a mapping of UUIDs with their player names.

Comment: This is the best I've got so far but it's not good enough. I'm hoping someone else will answer my question fully.